# How can i login with user's password in Wordpress being an admin?

Tags: users, login, password

I have a Wordpress website with a membership system, the issue is that some of my users are having problems logging in and the website gets stuck as they say. When i try it with my account, it works properly. So my question is there a way i can login with their account ( knowing that i don't have the password and am not going ask them for it ). I know that Wordpress encrypt the password, but what would be a good way to try to login in this case to investigate the problem for my users ?
Thanks,

Comment: in the database, you can replace the user's encrypted password with your encrypted password. an then you can log in on this accout with your password.

Comment: @mmm, why DB? he is the admin, he can just change it from the admin screens

Answer (score 1):

The user switching plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-switching/ is an essential tool when developing sites with multiple users. It lets admins switch to the user's acount without knowing his password (from the user admin page) and switch back.

This might be enough for diagnosing user specific problem, but if you still need to have admin capabilities at the same time, you will be out of luck, and will need to have a different session with a different browser.

Regardless of that specific plugin, you should always have some "test users" as it is unlikely live users will appreciate you messing with their accounts if any configuration changes are needed. Don't forget to have a strong password for those users as well.

Comment: I'd recommend ever having the ability to login as users other than your own.  Opens many liability doors.

Comment: @rudtek that is true. hence test users, or use that plugin on test site, but sometimes you just need a way to see the user's settings

Answer (score 0):

Create a user account of your own that is separate from your admin account.  Do your testing with this account.  I use a 2nd broswer (ie I normally use firefox, but for the testing account open Chrome) so I can be logged in with my admin and the test account at the same time.

Comment: The idea is that i need to login with other user's account, not my account ! The problem is that i need to investigate issues happening with one of my user's account.

Comment: private mode can probably also be useful